# TFS Upgrade Fakes Build error

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, microsoft-fakes

We just migrated to TFS 2015 from 2013, and now getting lots of TFS Build errors when building fakes. There are many errors that look like this (Admin web app has a test project called Admin.tests): `The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. [C:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)\f3651c6c\TeamProject\WebApps\Admin\Admin.Tests\obj\Release\Fakes\ctp\f.csproj]`.
Those solutions build locally just fine or under TFS2013 Build system. Is there anything in fakes configuration that need to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had many issues with Fakes on the build server and the only way we've worked around it for the time being was to check in the Fakes/ and FakesAssemblies/ folders into TFS.

This of course adds problems though when compiling locally because the files are read only now that they are source controlled.

We are actually migrating away from using Fakes and instead sticking to a Mocking framework like MoQ.

Comment: Thanks. We resolved this issue but not before consolidating Fakes into a single project and referencing it from all Test projects, then manipulating Test step settings. I agree MoQ would be much better choice and will migrate eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Two soln:

1) Make Sure "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build" ticked.

Go to Tools --> Options --> Package Manager --> General

2) It looks like you have wrong version of EntityFramework. Please download the correct version by using the NuGet package installer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The issue is not EntityFramework, the Microsoft Fakes is.as you can tell from that error. I get many errors like that on various types.